# Writing to multiple file-descriptors

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc

Is there any OS-level (Linux) speedup when writing one fixed byte buffer to many file-descriptors? When writing many buffers to one file-descriptor one can use `writev(2)`, so I wonder if there's any analogue to this or it must be done by multiple sys-calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know no such syscall on Linux. Their exhaustive list is given in the [syscalls(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) man page.

And I won't bother that much. For file access, the real bottleneck is the disk...

Comment: Except that writes don't go to the disk; all `write` does is copy the data to a buffer in the kernel.  (There are options to change this, but this is the default behavior.)  And the OP's question is a good one, since if there were such a question, it would mean one copy, and probably only one buffer in the kernel (less resources used in kernel).

Comment: I agree and I know that, but when you have enough RAM so that all hot files fit inside, you should not worry that much. I don't think that the kernel is able to share segments of files between distinct files.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I am not sure that the shared buffer would work. If you have two files, one on a SSD and one on a network drive far far away, should the SSD waits for the network drive ? Depending on the situation, you may prefer to have at least one file successfully written rather than two half-writes.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used it but this might work: lio_listio

http://linux.die.net/man/3/lio_listio

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `vmsplice` and `tee` should do what was requested, it's multiple calls thereof though, but the user-space/kernel-space barrier is crossed only once.

Comment: Thank you, but it's only for pipes.